# Getting a student loan and enrolling to a university in England

Tags: united-kingdom, students

As an EU citizen, who has been living in Britain for a year, can I get a student loan to pay for my tuition fees in one of the UK based universities?

Comment: You use England, Britain, and UK in your question, but the nuances of the answer are going to depend on what you mean. Further, what do you mean by a student loan. Do you mean a loan through [SLC](http://www.slc.co.uk/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system in the UK is confusing. As far as I can tell the Scotish system is different from the English, Welsh and Northern Irish systems. I assume you are talking about the government finances and not private loans. The requirements for qualifying are available from [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/student-finance/who-qualifies):

> You can only apply if:
>
> - you’re a UK national or have ‘settled status’ (no restrictions on how long you can stay)
> - you normally live in England
> - you’ve been living in the UK for 3 years before starting your course
>
> You may also be eligible if your residency status is one of the
>   following:
>
> - EU national, or family member of one
> - refugee
> - humanitarian protection (as a result of a failed application for asylum)
> - migrant worker
> - child of a Swiss national
> - child of a Turkish worker

Assuming you are not an UK citizen and don't have refugee status or humanitarian protection, you will not be able to apply with form [PN1](http://www.sfengland.slc.co.uk/media/559131/sfe_pn1_1314_d.pdf), but you may be able to apply and qualify with form [EU13N](http://www.sfengland.slc.co.uk/media/591405/eu13n_form_1314_d.pdf).